# objective C , setting the navigation bar background color

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, storyboard, uinavigationitem

I am making a storyboard application using XCode 4.2

I am trying to set the color of the background of the navigation bar but cant find anyway to do that.

I found a way to set the text  (see below), but not the title

```
    [[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"title text"];
```

I would like the background of the navigation bar to be black

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];
[bar setTintColor: [UIColor blackColor]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0.2 alpha:1];
```

the iOS5 has a flexible colorable ToolBar too.